# Combine “accumulate” and “takewhile”?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

The following makes a list natural even numbers up to 20, then makes a list of reductions, then finds index of an item satisfying a certain condition:

```
input = [x for x in range(20) if x%2 == 0]
accumulated_input = list(accumulate(input, func=operator.add))
len(list(takewhile(lambda a: a < 30, accumulated_input)))
```

(Yes, I can approach the problem with a simple `while` loop, but I am trying to figure out how things work in functional style.)

It seems that I am doing some unnecessary work. What is the idiomatic functional style approach? (Ideally, take even natural numbers one by one, add them up until a certain number is reached, and return the index of that number.)

Comment: 1. `operator.add` is the default for `accumulate` 2. you don't have to convert the `accumulate` iterator to `list`. Remove unnecessary variables and conversions, and you'll get `sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda a: a < 30, accumulate(range(0, 20, 2))))`

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Also, don't use `list(accumulate(...))`. That defeats the purpose of having these lazy iterators. It is much more efficient if you `takewhile` directly over the `accumulate` iterator.

Comment: Your current code is already functional, as there are no side effects. I would use the `sum` function btw to sum values.